# fact used in C*-algebra proofs.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Recently I have seen this argument being used a lot in the book I am reading. Namely the fact that if $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital $C^{*}$-algebra, let $\mathcal{A}_{+}$ be the collection of positive elements, and let $\mathcal{A}_{-} = \{ A: -A \in \mathcal{A}_{+} \}$ then $\mathcal{A}_{+} \cap \mathcal{A}_{-} = \{0 \}$, how can we just assume that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $x \in \mathcal{A}_+\cap \mathcal{A}_-$. Then $x \in \mathcal{A}_+$, so $\sigma_\mathcal{A}(x)\subseteq [0, \infty[$. On the other hand, $-x \in \mathcal{A}_+$, so $\sigma_\mathcal{A}(-x)\subseteq [0,\infty[$, and thus $\sigma_\mathcal{A}(x)\subseteq ]-\infty,0]$. Hence,
$$\sigma_\mathcal{A}(x)\subseteq ]-\infty,0]\cap [0, \infty[ = \{0\}$$
and thus $\sigma_\mathcal{A}(x)=0$. By assumption, $x$ is positive, so self-adjoint, so its norm equals its spectral radius. Hence, $x=0$, since the spectral radius is $0$.

Comment: for $x \in \mathcal{A}_{+}$ then $x \in \mathcal{A}_{+} \implies \sigma_{\mathcal{A}}(x) \subseteq [0, \infty [ $ because $x$ is self adjoint $\iff \sigma(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Fredf The definition of a positive element is a self-adjoint element with positive spectrum.

Comment: ahh yes of course.. it is right in front of me. Nice proof!

Comment: @Fredf Glad to help!

Comment: btw. I have only seen that ||x||=r(x) when $x$ is normal am I missing something obvious here..

Comment: @Fredf A self-adjoint element is normal: $xx^* = x^2 = x^*x$

Comment: YEP! you're right..